# Zustand - alternative to "slices" pattern

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, zustand

I have a React Native app that consists of modals (popups) showing up at different places. This can be a user login modal, a modal that allows a user to be added to a list of groups/orgs, a modal that allows editing a user profile etc. For all these types of modals, I decided to create a central state store using the [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) state management library.

Following the Zustand "slices" pattern mentioned [here](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/slices-pattern), I was able to get the following structure for each type of Modal -

- Slices

  - *useEditUserProfileModalSlice.ts*

  ```
  export const createEditUserProfileModalSlice = (set) => ({
      isEditUserProfileModalOpen: false,
      openEditUserProfileModal: () => set(() => ({ isEditUserProfileModalOpen: true })),
      closeEditUserProfileModal: () => set(() => ({ isEditUserProfileModalOpen: false }))
  });
  ```

  - *useAddUserToOrgModalSlice.ts*

  ```
  export const createAddUserToOrgModalSlice = (set) => ({
      isAddUserToOrgModalOpen: false,
      openAddUserToOrgModal: () => set(() => ({ isAddUserToOrgModalOpen: true })),
      closeAddUserToOrgModal: () => set(() => ({ isAddUserToOrgModalOpen: false }))
  });
  ```
- Store

  *useModalStore.ts*

  ```
  import create from 'zustand'

  export const useModalStore = create((...a) => ({
    ...createEditUserProfileModalSlice(...a),
    ...createAddUserToOrgModalSlice(...a),
  }))
  ```
- Usage

```
const isEditUserProfileModalOpen = useModalStore((state) => state.isEditUserProfileModalOpen);
const openEditUserProfileModal = useModalStore((state) => state.openEditUserProfileModal);
const closeEditUserProfileModal = useModalStore((state) => state.closeEditUserProfileModal);
```

Is there an alternative to this pattern that you would recommend?
I ask because any time I need to add a new modal type, I'll need to create a new slice file, with basically the same 3 properties (isOpen, open function and close function), which kinda seems boilerplate-y.

Comment: What about one global state where you have a record name modal with key as modal name and modal status as value. When you call `openEditUserProfileModal ` or `closeEditUserProfileModal ` function, pass the modal key to each functions and update the state accordingly